# I need to create a system with dynamic rules created/edited bythe user on the UI using aspnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dynamic, nrules

I need to create a system with dynamic rules created/edited bythe user on the UI using aspnet core. I researched some frameworks and the best i found was the NRULES, but i belive that is not gonna solve my problem. Anyone has some advise about how to do this? Or any tool or framework that i can use instead of creating all the logic.

Thanks A lot.

Comment: Use some Script...!! Python/ Iron Python... JavaScript. So all the UI will have to do is to allow editing text script file. I would incline towards JavaScript - as Python requires Tab spacing to be perfect which I see as a problem on WebUI. If you want the rules to be run and managed from C# then you have to pick IronPython.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a late answer. Stick to NRules, it allows for dynamic rules. There are many complex rule engines you can buy, but if you want to roll your own - your best bet is to figure out what the rules are first and how deep you want the rules to be layered. i.e. some complex business processes require thousands of lines of code to meet the business requirement. Also, building UI for rules can get out of hand if you don't know the complexity of the rules you are trying to build. So find the most complex rules in your business domain and build backwards otherwise there is no end to rules development as rules constantly change.